# AngularJS passing params data in a specific order using $http.get request

Tags: ajax, angularjs, get, javascript

I'm using **AngularJS** in a simple prototype app that uses **Domino** server on the back end.

When I do a seemingly simple call like this:

```
$http({ url: $scope.hrEventsPath, 
        method : "GET", 
        params : { 'readform' : '',
                   'eventid' : $scope.queryStringPairs.eventid,
                   'userid' : $scope.queryStringPairs.userid,
                   'login' : $scope.queryStringPairs.login } }).
            success(function(data, status) {
                // happy stuff
            }).
            error(function(data, status) {
                // error handling stuff
            });
```

It seems that Angular puts all the params in alphabetical order when the call is made.

Therefore, the `readform` parameter is not the first parameter, `eventid` is, and the Domino server chokes. (This happens whether or not '`readform`' has a value)

Regardless of Domino and its configuration, is there a way to for a sort the order in Angularm or should one use another approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of single objects, then the object won't have a chance to switch itself around.

```
[ {}, {}, {} ]
```

Comment: to add onto your answer, here's why the answer works. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L1014

By default angular sorts all the param keys if passed as a single object.

Comment: Thanks @StenMuchow, and thanks for the extra on why it behaves that way.

Comment: While passing in a an array of objects to `params` preserves the order, it doesn't produce the same URL as passing in an object of attributes. What am I missing to get the order working?

`params: { query: 5, other: 2 }` produces `?query=5&other=2`

Passing in the array of objects does this:
`params: [{query: 5}, {other: 2}]` produces `?0=%7B%22query%22:5%7D&1=%7B%22other%22:2%7D`

Comment: do you have some code example to check out? maybe a plunker?

Comment: @StenMuchow here's a jsbin with the code - http://jsbin.com/canedu/14/edit?js,console You can toggle between the two methods `getOrderedParams` and `getParams` in the $http code to see the different URL being generated. You can ignore the fact the endpoint is returning an error because CORS isn't enabled, we just want to see the URL generated in console as an example.